Macro Button that clears constants AND a specific formula
I need a macro for a button that will encompass E2:E180 and only delete constants (or input values) AND the formula "=Left(b..."
I currently use a macro that, on single click, inputs "=LEFT(B" & R & ", 3)" into the active cell; however, I also have other formulae in this column that I want to keep there, like:
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(E267,"TRUE"),COUNTIF(E21,"M*")),"SS","")
=e9 ... etc.
=IFNA(E273,"")
=IF(E39>0,E39,"")

and some others.
I originally tried making a simple macro that cleared the contents of specific cells, but the range selection was too long and would involved editing too many numbers if I was to ever insert a row.
I eventually settled on:
    With Worksheets("MISC.")
        .Range("H4:H182").Copy
    End With
        Range("E2").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll UP:=150
    Range("E3").Select

this basically copies an identical column from the back of the workbook and pastes it over top of the active one. This works, but I would like to know if there is a cleaner way to clear the cells around the important formula without convoluting the code.
In summation, I need a macro that will only target constants and =LEFT(b2,b3,b4,b5... etc.

What do you mean by "delete constants (or input values)"? The same for "AND the formula "=Left(b..."... To delete any constant (*"which is not the result of a formula**) in that range? If so, what  "(or input values)" should mean? And what to do with formula starting with "=Left(b..."? To clear it or to transform the result in value/constant?

Please, try the next way, not needing any iteration...
Sub procConstFormulae()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
 
 Set ws = ActiveSheet
 Set rng = ws.Range("E2:E180")
 With rng
    On Error Resume Next
     .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Formula = "=""""" 'place nullstring formula instead of constants
     .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Formula = "="""""    'place nullstring formula instead of empty strings
    On Error GoTo 0
    'keep something else than formulae starting with "=Left(B"
    .Formula = Evaluate("IF(LEFT(FORMULATEXT(" & rng.address & "),7)=""=Left(B"","""",FORMULATEXT(" & rng.address & "))")
    .Replace "=""""", "" 'replace the previous empty string formulae, placed to not bother the above formula...
 End With
End Sub

Edited:
I found an even more compact way. Please, test the next version:
Sub procConstFormulae_()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
 Set ws = ActiveSheet: Set rng = ws.Range("E2:E180")
 
 With rng
    'keep something else than formulae starting with "=Left(B" and return #N/A (string) for no formulae or blank cells:
    .Formula = Evaluate("IF(LEFT(FORMULATEXT(" & rng.address & "),7)=""=Left(B"","""",FORMULATEXT(" & rng.address & "))")
    On Error Resume Next 'for the case of no blank or constant cells:
     .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents 'the previous line returns errors AS STRING (#N/A) for no formulae cells
    On Error GoTo 0
 End With
End Sub


You're digging yourself in deeper: "'xlCellTypeBlanks are considered the blank result of a formula, too" is not true. xlCellTypeBlanks refers only to empty cells, the ones for which in VBA, IsEmpty returns True, or in Excel, ISBLANK returns TRUE. Therefore the line .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).ClearContents will always be redundant but it can still raise the "No cells were found." error if there are no empty cells in the range.

@VBasic2008 Yes, you are right, thanks! I was in a hurry and (I thought) I tested. Wrongly, of course... I will adapt the code to simple use Replace which should do the job in a simpler way. And I will test it after that... :) Did it! And made two tests. No to much availability for intensive testing, even now...

Hey Fane, sorry for the late response... hectic week. This worked perfectly and I was able to understand each step. Thank for the help, brother!

@Quasar Glad I could help! I think (now) that it is possible to make it more compact... If what I have in my mind is confirmed, I will edit the answer and place (such) a new version.

@fane works great; I threw in another exclusion that I overlooked. Very easy to understand. Thank you, again!

@Quasar This is the main purpose  of this community existence. To make people learn...

@FaneDuru for the -range("e2:e180")- is there a way to get that to reference the column that the form control is in? something like topleftcell?

@Quasar  Are you talking about a UserForm? If so, the short answer to your question would be: No, such a property belong only to the sheet objects. The long one may be Even not existing such a property, it should be possible to calculate it. Complicated, using API functions. Range.Top represents the distance, in points, from the top of row 1 to the top edge of the respective range, and UserForm.Top is related to (top of the) Screen. If you place a question, but well defined about you need and I will be available (if you tag me here) I will try helping. If not, somebody else.

@Quasar When I said well defined about you need, the best idea would be to say if you need to position the form on a specific cell (complicated, but simpler against the following alternative) or to determine on which cell the form has its right top corner (much more complicated...).

@Quasar  So, don't you need any of the two possible versions? Did you only want knowing if it is possible...?

Clear Constants and Specific Formulas
Sub ClearConstants()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "E2"
    Const EXCLUDE_FORMULA_PATTERN As String = "=LEFT(B" & "*" & ",3)"
    
    ' Reference the objects.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    
    Dim rg As Range, RowsCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range(FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
        RowsCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If RowsCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox "No data found in ""'" & ws.Name & "'!" _
                & .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).Address(0, 0) & """!", _
                vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set rg = .Resize(RowsCount)
    End With
    
    ' Return the formulas in an array (replace constants with empty strings).
    
    Dim EvaluateFormulaString As String:
    EvaluateFormulaString = "IFNA(FORMULATEXT(" & rg.Address & "),"""")"
    
    Dim Data() As Variant
    
    If RowsCount = 1 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        Data(1, 1) = ws.Evaluate(EvaluateFormulaString)
    Else
        Data = ws.Evaluate(EvaluateFormulaString)
    End If
    
    ' Replace each Exclude formula with an empty string.

    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To RowsCount
        If Len(Data(r, 1)) > 0 Then
            If Data(r, 1) Like EXCLUDE_FORMULA_PATTERN Then
                Data(r, 1) = vbNullString
            End If
        End If
    Next r
     
    ' Copy the array back to the range (empty strings yield in empty cells).
     
    rg.Value = Data

End Sub


sorry for the late response, buddy! This did not clear the =left(b... formulae, but it did clear the constants. I appreciate the help! Fane's code did the trick.
